# Upgrading ubuntu lead to a new, broken version, but the old one still runs

Tags: upgrade

Don't know what else to add.

GRUB now presents 2 x 2 options. Using the older version works fine, using the new one (regular and fail safe) doesn't work. I'd like to be up to date, but also to actually have the newest version working.

Not working = when I choose it, I end up on a black screen, "forever" (more than 1 minute).

Ubuntu installed as wubi, in windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems appearing after upgrades. Maybe try this:

1. Backup any files you have in the Ubuntu to a USB drive.
2. Enter Windows 7 and  uninstall ubuntu. From how you described your setup, this will probably remove both installations of Ubuntu.
3. Restart Windows, then use Wubi to install a fresh copy of 11.10.

Did this exact procedure earlier today. No more post-upgrade problems. Direct install seems to be the most trouble-free.

Does that help?

Comment: This was my first upgrade after a fresh install of a slightly old version. Is there no way to upgrade to the newest? Only fresh install?

Comment: There is probably a way to get the update working, but in your question you stated you wanted both the newest version, and to be 'up to date'. Installing 11.10 fresh is the most time-effective solution for meeting both needs. Unless you have a compelling reason for keeping your old installation, you may accomplish your goals quicker by installing a fresh copy of 11.10 using wubi. Does that help?

Comment: I recently did a fresh install of what GRUB calls 2.6.38-8, This was my first upgrade after that fresh install, and brought me to 2.6.38-11, or it should have. I am reluctant to do another fresh install again, already, unless I know it will actually work, and it's the only way.